# How do you create a read-only user in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to create a user in PostgreSQL that can only do SELECTs from a particular database. In MySQL the command would be:

```
GRANT SELECT ON mydb.* TO 'xxx'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'yyy';
```

What is the equivalent command or series of commands in PostgreSQL?

I tried...

```
postgres=# CREATE ROLE xxx LOGIN PASSWORD 'yyy';
postgres=# GRANT SELECT ON DATABASE mydb TO xxx;
```

But it appears that the only things you can grant on a database are CREATE, CONNECT, TEMPORARY, and TEMP.

Answer (score 871, accepted):

### Grant usage/select to a single table

If you only grant CONNECT to a database, the user can connect but has no other privileges. You have to grant USAGE on namespaces (schemas) and SELECT on tables and views individually like so:

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb TO xxx;
-- This assumes you're actually connected to mydb..
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO xxx;
GRANT SELECT ON mytable TO xxx;
```

### Multiple tables/views (PostgreSQL 9.0+)

In the latest versions of PostgreSQL, you can grant permissions on all tables/views/etc in the schema using a single command rather than having to type them one by one:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO xxx;
```

This only affects tables that have already been created. More powerfully, you can automatically have [default roles assigned to new objects](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) in future:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public
   GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO xxx;
```

Note that by default this will only affect objects (tables) created by the user that issued this command: although it can also be set on any role that the issuing user is a member of. However, you don't pick up default privileges for all roles you're a member of when creating new objects... so there's still some faffing around. If you adopt the approach that a database has an owning role, and schema changes are performed as that owning role, then you should assign default privileges to that owning role. IMHO this is all a bit confusing and you may need to experiment to come up with a functional workflow.

### Multiple tables/views (PostgreSQL versions before 9.0)

To avoid errors in lengthy, multi-table changes, it is recommended to use the following 'automatic' process to generate the required `GRANT SELECT` to each table/view:

```
SELECT 'GRANT SELECT ON ' || relname || ' TO xxx;'
FROM pg_class JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace
WHERE nspname = 'public' AND relkind IN ('r', 'v', 'S');
```

This should output the relevant GRANT commands to GRANT SELECT on all tables, views, and sequences in public, for copy-n-paste love. Naturally, this will only be applied to tables that have already been created.

Comment: You should put your edit concerning PG9 at the top of the post.

Comment: If you have several schemas, you may also need to set the `search_path`. For example, to extract stuff from my Mediawiki install, I needed to add `ALTER ROLE backup_bot SET search_path=mediawiki, public;`.

Comment: @mivk presumably you could have worked around that by prefixing table names with "mediawiki."; but yes, this is a trap to be aware of when moving beyond a system with one user and the tables in a schema named after them.

Comment: Nice. One thing I'd add is that you may also need to allow sequences to be read by this user; so: GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO xxx;

Comment: Note that to prevent this user from being able to create new tables, I had to `REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;`. Without that, the "read only" user couldn't modify existing tables, but could create new tables in the schema and add/remove data from those tables.

Comment: @Ajedi32 This should be part of the accepted answer! Thanks

Comment: For the newbies like me I think it's worth mentionning that you should start the console using `psql mydb` otherwise most of these manipulations wouldn't do. It personally took me a considerable amount of time to figure it out by my own. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Be careful with `public` schema.It already has a lot of default privileges that you maybe don't want... See documentation [here][1].


  [1]: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PRIV

Comment: You can use `\connect db_name;` to connect to the database before `GRANT USAGE...` in a sql file, otherwise the permissions won't work.

Comment: I have a query regarding adding a new user to postgres. I am having a couple of tables in production with ~100M records to which I need to create read-only access for a new user. Will the size of my table cause any issues? Approximately how much time it will take to create this user with correct permissions?

Answer (score 204):

**[Reference taken from this blog:](http://www.dbrnd.com/2015/10/postgresql-script-to-create-a-read-only-database-user/)**

**Script to Create Read-Only user:**

```
CREATE ROLE Read_Only_User WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'Test1234';
\connect YourDatabaseName;
```

**Assign permission to this read-only user:**

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE YourDatabaseName TO Read_Only_User;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO Read_Only_User;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO Read_Only_User;

-- [Optional] Use with care
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO Read_Only_User;
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
```

***Assign permissions to read all newly tables created in the future***

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO Read_Only_User;
```

Comment: This is a very good answer except one thing missing:

```ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO Read_Only_User;```

which would also allow to read all tables created in same DB in the future.

Comment: It's unusual to allow a read-only user access to the sequences. Reading the sequence updates it, and they're typically only needed for `INSERT`s.

Comment: For completeness, possibly add: `GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA schema_name TO Read_Only_User;`

Comment: @jpmc26: does that mean that you recommend: `GRANT ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA schema_name TO Read_Only_User`?

Comment: @FabienHaddadi It means that unless you have some out of the ordinary requirement, I don't see a need to grant any permissions on sequences to a read only user.

Comment: @jpmc26: in my experience, I occasionally check sequences after a dump injection to a new schema, as some operations may make them out-of-sync, hence creating dup errors on the primary key at the next insert. checking a nextval and comparing it against the MAX(PK) can be used as a QA process.

Comment: @FabienHaddadi The best way to prevent those is to use a point-in-time snapshot for creating the dump (`--serializable-deferrable` will do it). Aside from that, I wouldn't use a read-only user to repair corrupted data imports, anyway.

Comment: It's important to point out that the instructions from `GRANT USAGE...` onwards (like the GRANT permissions on tables) should be run in the desired database, otherwise the permissions won't work. To do that, you can `\connect db_name;` to connect to the database (it can be used in a sql file too).

Comment: As stated by Lucas Basquerotto, you need to `\c db_name`. Please read this!

Comment: `NO...` is the default for `SUPERUSER` etc. No need to specify it.

Comment: There's a race condition here. If someone runs the grants and alters in the order you've shown them, a new table could be created between the `GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES ...` and the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES ...`, in which case that table will not be granted to the user. To be sure no tables are missed, these commands should be run in the opposite order.

Answer (score 92):

From PostgreSQL v14 on, you can do that simply by granting the predefined [`pg_read_all_data`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/predefined-roles.html#PREDEFINED-ROLES-TABLE) role:

```
GRANT pg_read_all_data TO xxx;
```

Comment: However, to the best of my understanding this grants read only access to all databases in the instance, not to a specific database, right?

Comment: @adamo Correct; and it is crude.

Comment: Perfect for my use case of a single grant allowing read access across all databases, for existing and future tables.

Answer (score 53):

Do note that PostgreSQL 9.0 (today in beta testing) will have a [simple way to do that](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-grant.html):

```
test=> GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO joeuser;
```

Comment: I had to be in the specific database for this to work. Postgresql 9.5.

Comment: This works only for existing tables in the schema. If the write-user later creates or replaces tables, the readonly user will not have access to them

Answer (score 29):

**Here is the best way I've found to add read-only users (using PostgreSQL 9.0 or newer):**

```
$ sudo -upostgres psql postgres
postgres=# CREATE ROLE readonly WITH LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '<USE_A_NICE_STRONG_PASSWORD_PLEASE';
postgres=# GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO readonly;
```

Then log in to all related machines (master + read-slave(s)/hot-standby(s), etc..) and run:

```
$ echo "hostssl <PUT_DBNAME_HERE> <PUT_READONLY_USERNAME_HERE> 0.0.0.0/0 md5" | sudo tee -a /etc/postgresql/9.2/main/pg_hba.conf
$ sudo service postgresql reload
```

Comment: I like the approach but I also needed to GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE [thedatabase] TO [theuser or role]; and GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO [theuser or role];

Comment: The public schema still allows such a user to create tables. Also, new tables aren't covered, nor are sequences. Unfortunately, this is all quite a bit more complicated than this. :-/ I'll post what I ended up doing once I've validated it some more.

Comment: In your above script you are trying to create the role twice. I suspect that you intended to use "ALTER ROLE ..." when enabling the role for login and setting the password

Comment: If you already have the user, after creating the readonly role and grant select perms grant the new role to the user: GRANT readonly TO <USER>

Answer (score 28):

By default new users will have permission to create tables. If you are planning to create a read-only user, this is probably not what you want.

To create a true read-only user with PostgreSQL 9.0+, run the following steps:

```
# This will prevent default users from creating tables
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM public;

# If you want to grant a write user permission to create tables
# note that superusers will always be able to create tables anyway
GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA public to writeuser;

# Now create the read-only user
CREATE ROLE readonlyuser WITH LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'strongpassword';
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO readonlyuser;
```

If your read-only user doesn't have permission to list tables (i.e. `\d` returns no results), it's probably because you don't have `USAGE` permissions for the schema. `USAGE` is a permission that allows users to actually use the permissions they have been assigned. What's the point of this? I'm not sure. To fix:

```
# You can either grant USAGE to everyone
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO public;

# Or grant it just to your read only user
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO readonlyuser;
```

Answer (score 10):

I’ve created a convenient script for that; [pg_grant_read_to_db.sh](https://gist.github.com/jirutka/afa3ce62b1430abf7572#file-pg_grant_read_to_db-sh). This script grants read-only privileges to a specified role on all tables, views and sequences in a database schema and sets them as default.

Comment: Very useful, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I read trough all the possible solutions, which are all fine, if you remember to connect to the database before you grant the things ;) Thanks anyway to all other solutions!!!

```
user@server:~$ sudo su - postgres
```

create psql user:

```
postgres@server:~$ createuser --interactive 
Enter name of role to add: readonly
Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) n
Shall the new role be allowed to create databases? (y/n) n
Shall the new role be allowed to create more new roles? (y/n) n
```

start psql cli and set a password for the created user:

```
postgres@server:~$ psql
psql (10.6 (Ubuntu 10.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), server 9.5.14)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# alter user readonly with password 'readonly';
ALTER ROLE
```

connect to the target database:

```
postgres=# \c target_database 
psql (10.6 (Ubuntu 10.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), server 9.5.14)
You are now connected to database "target_database" as user "postgres".
```

grant all the needed privileges:

```
target_database=# GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE target_database TO readonly;
GRANT

target_database=# GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO readonly ;
GRANT

target_database=# GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO readonly ;
GRANT
```

alter default privileges for targets db public shema:

```
target_database=# ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readonly;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
```

Answer (score 5):

If your database is in the public schema, it is easy (this assumes you have already created the `readonlyuser`)

```
db=> GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public to readonlyuser;
GRANT
db=> GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydatabase to readonlyuser;
GRANT
db=> GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public to readonlyuser;
GRANT
```

If your database is using `customschema`, execute the above but add one more command:

```
db=> ALTER USER readonlyuser SET search_path=customschema, public;
ALTER ROLE
```

Answer (score 3):

The not straightforward way of doing it would be granting select on each table of the database:

```
postgres=# grant select on db_name.table_name to read_only_user;
```

You could automate that by generating your grant statements from the database metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from a link posted in response to [despesz'](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2007/10/19/grantall/) link.

Postgres 9.x appears to have the capability to do what is requested.  See the Grant On Database Objects paragraph of:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-grant.html

Where it says: "There is also an option to grant privileges on all objects of the same type within one or more schemas. This functionality is currently supported only for tables, sequences, and functions (but note that ALL TABLES is considered to include views and foreign tables)."

This page also discusses use of ROLEs and a PRIVILEGE called "ALL PRIVILEGES".

Also present is information about how GRANT functionalities compare to SQL standards.

Answer (score 0):

DB Tool: PGAdmin 4

```
CREATE USER readonly_user2 WITH PASSWORD 'Pass@123';  
-- readonly_user2 = UserName, Pass@123 = Password

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE employeedb TO readonly_user2;  
-- employeedb = Your Database Name 

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO readonly_user2;

GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO readonly_user2;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readonly_user2;  
-- automatically grant the access to future created tables
```

Answer (score -11):

```
CREATE USER username SUPERUSER  password 'userpass';
ALTER USER username set default_transaction_read_only = on;
```

Comment: This is a huge security risk. The first command issued by the user just needs to be:

set transaction_read_only = off;

Comment: Rasjid is right. Please do not run this command on any DB, always change at least 'username' to something other and 'userpass' to something secure.