# Read-only user able to create table

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-permissions

I created a read-only user in PostgreSQL and it is still able to create tables:

I created a test DB and then created a `readonly2` user. Gave it only select privileges on 2 tables. When I log into this DB as `readonly2` user I am still able to create tables:

```
create database test1
create user readonly2 with password 'readonly';
grant select on test1 to readonly2
grant select on test2 to readonly2
```

where `test1` and `test2` are 2 tables in test DB.

Now when I log into the test DB as `readonly2` user, I am able to create tables:

```
test=> create table test55 (id int);
CREATE TABLE
```

I just want to create a read-only user with select permissions. I do not want to grant create table permissions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760210/how-do-you-create-a-read-only-user-in-postgresql

Answer (score 8):

Every table is created in a schema in Postgres. To create a table, a role must have the `CREATE` privilege for the *schema*. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-grant.html)

> CREATE
>
> ... For schemas, allows new objects to be created within the schema.

The default schema for a table to be created in is the first schema of the current [`search_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777).

The first schema in the search_path is typically the schema with the same name as the user or the schema `public`.

And the [`public` schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PUBLIC) comes with default privileges:

> A user can also be allowed to create objects in someone else's schema.
>   To allow that, the `CREATE` privilege on the schema needs to be granted.
>   Note that by default, **everyone has `CREATE` and `USAGE` privileges on the
>   schema public**.

Bold emphasis mine.

You can change that:

```
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
```

Be sure to think about consequences first ...

(Either that, or the role is a superuser.)

Comment: I did the same.. Revoked create privileges from this user `revoke create on schema public from readonly2` restarted DB engine and even then i was able to create table in the test DB

Comment: @user3669651: But it's *not* the same. Revoking privileges from `readonly2` doesn't change the fact that *every* user can create tables in the `public` schema until you revoke from role `public` ...