# Database Schema Right Issue

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-8.4

I am using postgresql. I have created a user and grant access on db. I want user can only see granted schema objects and rest database/schema objects can't watchable. Please guide me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760210/how-do-you-create-a-read-only-user-in-postgresql?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter the user and set the search path.

```
ALTER USER foo SET search_path TO '$newschema,pg_catalog';
```

Note that in order to get a proper backup of globals such as this you have to use pg_dumpall -g, not pg_dump. Obviously a base backup will have them as well.

Comment: alter user ali set search_path TO 'usman';  still not working and ali able to see other schema objects.

Comment: You can not completely remove other schema visibility on its own. You need search_path plus a series of GRANT/REVOKE statements.