# Select * query for granted columns in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I granted permission for read_only user in postgres for some columns of a table using

```
grant select(col1,col2) on mytable to read_only_user;
```

I want to use

```
SELECT * FROM  mytable
```

query from read_only_user.But I'm getting permission denied in output.I don't want to create view for this. But somehow I want the **select *** query to work for that user(not explicitly telling what are the columns like **select col1,col2 from mytable**).

Help me guys.Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you grant usage on the schema as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760210/how-do-you-create-a-read-only-user-in-postgresql

Comment: i can use "select col1,col2 from mytable" this query and it is working . but i want select * query.- @NPras

Comment: Ah, sorry I misunderstood. So if you have `col1..5`, you want that particular user to only be presented with `col1, col2` when doing a `SELECT *`? I don't believe that's possible in postgre (or any others that I know of).

Comment: `select *` states you want to see all columns - however you do not have the privilege to see all columns.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually Npras got my point. Do you know any ways to do that? If i have grantend 30 out of 50 column , then every time i need to write the all allowed column names in query. that's why i ask this

Comment: Create a view with only those columns

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do that, and you shouldn't try.

`SELECT *` should *never* be used in code, it is only for ad hoc queries.
What are the problems:

- If the table definition changes, your program will break.
- You probably retrieve unnecessary columns, which will cause unnecessary data to be processed and may keep PostgreSQL from choosing a better execution plan.