# Create PostgreSQL user with read-only permission on AWS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, privileges

I'm trying to create a user with read-only permission in Postgres on AWS.

```
CREATE USER readonly_username WITH PASSWORD 'password';
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public to readonly_username;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readonly_username;
```

After that i gave SELECT permission new tables:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readonly_username;
```

But when i try to give permission to existing tables i got an error:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO readonly_username;
```

**ERROR:  permission denied for relation admin_log**

Can anyone help me?

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760210/how-do-you-create-a-read-only-user-in-postgresql

Comment: Looks like you don't own the table `admin_log`.