# How to create an immutable copy of the django model in python?

Tags: python, django, immutability

I want to create an immutable copy of the model instance, such that the user be able to access the details of the model, including its attributes, but not the `save` and the `delete` methods.
The use case is that there are two repos accessing the django model, where one is supposed to have a writable access to the model, while another should only have a readable access to it.

I have been researching ways of doing this. One way, I could think is the readable repo gets the model instance with a wrapper, which is a class containing the model instance as a private variable.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    field1=models.CharField(max_length=11)
class ModelWrapper:
    def __init__(self,instance):
        self.__instance=instance
    def __getattr__(self,name):
        self.__instance.__getattr__(name)
```

The obvious problem with this approach is that the user can access the instance from the wrapper instance:

```
# model_wrapper is the wrapper created around the instance. Then
# model_wrapper._ModelWrapper__instance refers to the ModelA instance. Thus
instance = model_wrapper._ModelWrapper__instance
instance.field2="changed"
instance.save()
```

Thus, he would be able to update the value. Is there a way to restrict this behaviour?

Comment: In addition to the django model answers, consider using the DB's `GRANT` statements to ensure no accidental access occurs,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/762649/1464664

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding the models save and delete in webapp where you want to restrict that:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    field1=models.CharField(max_length=11)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return # Or raise an exception if needed
    
    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return # Or raise an exception if needed
```

If you are using update or delete on a queryset you might also need a pre_save and pre_delete signal:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=ModelA)
def pre_delete_handler(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        raise Exception('Cannot delete')
```

**Edit**: Looks like querysets don't send the pre_save/post_save signal so that cannot be used there, the delete signals are emitted though.

Comment: Yes. This method exactly works. Though, I was thinking, if I add the signal to the wrapper. So, the pre_delete signals are overriden only when they are called from the wrapper, it is not working. Is there a way to setup the receiver from the init method of the wrapper class?

Comment: @phoenix97 Signals are emitted when a model is updated / deleted I don't know how you would only receive a signal if the model is inside a wrapper unless you customize all of that. Can you add a variable in your settings.py to indicate whether writing is allowed on a model according to the repo / indicate which repo it is? If so I can submit another answer which may work for you.

Answer (score 1):

```py
class ModelA(models.Model):
    field1=models.CharField(max_length=11)

class ModelWrapper:
    def __init__(self, instance):
        self.__instance=instance

        # Delete unwanted attributes
        delattr(self.__instance, 'save') 
        delattr(self.__instance, 'delete')
    def __getattr__(self,name):
        self.__instance.__getattr__(name)
```

Comment: Getting the error: `AttributeError: save` on applying this?