# How to provide read only access to all existing databases in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

what's the recommended way to provide readonly access to all databases in `postgresql version 12`.

I am using this found at [How do you create a read-only user in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760210/how-do-you-create-a-read-only-user-in-postgresql)

```
CREATE ROLE readaccess;
CREATE USER my_user_test WITH PASSWORD 'my_user_test';

GRANT readaccess TO my_user_test;
\c database_name;

-- need to connect to the database first on which we need to execute the below commands
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE database_name TO readaccess;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO readaccess;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO readaccess;

-- Assign permissions to read all newly tables created in the future
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readaccess;
```

But using this approach I need to individually connect to `each database`  and provide the role read only access.

Is there a better approach to provide a read only access all existing databases at once?

Thanks.

Comment: You should read  the docs before depending on a 13 year old answer. Or at least look at the newer answers, for instance the one from Laurenz Albe which points you at the docs [Postgres pre-defined roles](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/predefined-roles.html)

Comment: Thanks Adrian, this is helpful. sorry i missed informing in the question that i am trying to accomplish this on `v12`

Comment: Ahh, that would make a difference. Then the method you are using is about as good as it gets.